# forcing __proto__ equality

Tags: javascript, oop

I want the prototype of these instances to be the same, but the following equality check evaluates to false.

```
var emp1 = new(EmployeeScope())("John");
var emp2 = new(EmployeeScope())("Amit");
var mgr1 = new(ManagerScope())("Robert", "Data");
var mgr2 = new(ManagerScope())("Alex", "Science");
emp1.getName() // John
emp2.getName() // Amit
mgr1.getDept() // Data
mgr2.getDept() // Science
mgr1.getName() // Robert
mgr2.getName() // Alex

emp1.__proto__ === emp2.__proto__ //false
mgr1.__proto__ === mgr2.__proto__ //false
```

---

```
function EmployeeScope() {
  var name;

  function Employee(newName) {
    name = newName;
  }
  Employee.prototype.getName = function() {
    return name
  };
  Employee.prototype.setName = function(newName) {
    name = newName
  };
  return Employee;
}

function ManagerScope() {
  var Employee = EmployeeScope();
  var dept;

  function Manager(newName, newDept) {
    new Employee(newName);
    dept = newDept;
  }
  Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
  Manager.prototype.constructor = Manager;
  Manager.prototype.getDept = function() {
    return dept
  };
  Manager.prototype.setDept = function(newDept) {
    dept = newDept
  };
  return Manager;
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about programming style and design belong on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Okay I am deleting this question. Shall ask on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Well hold on, there is something that is not working as you want it, so from that respect it belongs here.

Comment: okay Shall hold on

Comment: It seems others have decided differently. I suppose you should have asked your question differently, focussing on the *problem* you have, skipping the OOP story and that it works, since that gives the impression you are asking something that does not belong here.

Comment: I have reworded the question to fit the scope

Comment: Let's see if others will vote to reopen this question.

Comment: Might want to change the title as well, since your question seems specific to `__proto__`, not really about OOP per se (which has been asked about many, many times).

Comment: I am new here. Can anyone tell me what should I do next. I have done all that was asked... reworded the question and title to fit the scope

Comment: WTH is `EmployeeScope()` good for? Can you please comment how you intended the code to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the two objects have different prototypes is that the constructor functions `Employee` and `Manager` are created again at each call of the wrapper functions you put them in. So they represent *different* constructors when called in different calls of the wrapper functions.

A common solution to let the object methods access private members, is by defining them not on the prototype, but on the instances. That way you can define them in the constructor scope:

```js
function Employee(newName) {
    var name = newName;
    this.getName = function() {
        return name
    };
    this.setName = function(newName) {
        name = newName
    };
}

function Manager(newName, newDept) {
    var dept = newDept;
    // Inherit from Employee
    Employee.call(this, newName);

    this.getDept = function() {
        return dept
    };
    this.setDept = function(newDept) {
        dept = newDept
    };
}

var emp1 = new Employee("John");
var emp2 = new Employee("Amit");
var mgr1 = new Manager("Robert", "Data");
var mgr2 = new Manager("Alex", "Science");

console.log(emp1.getName()) // John
console.log(emp2.getName()) // Amit
console.log(mgr1.getDept()) // Data
console.log(mgr2.getDept()) // Science
console.log(mgr1.getName()) // Robert
console.log(mgr2.getName()) // Alex

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(emp1) === Object.getPrototypeOf(emp2)); 
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(mgr1) === Object.getPrototypeOf(mgr2));
```

Note that it is advised to use [`Object.getPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) instead of `__proto__`.

Secondly, you should declare local variables with `var` (or `let`, `const`), because otherwise the variable is silently declared as a global variable, and you would get the same name for every employee.

Comment: I had thought of this approach. It changes the output of getName(). All calls to getName() returns the name of the last created employee....

Comment: That is because `var` is missing in the declaration of the `name` in the Employee constructor: it then becomes a global variable. But with `var` it works.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's easier to understand why they don't share the same prototype when you write the code as following:

```
var EmployeeA = EmployeeScope();
var EmployeeB = EmployeeScope();
EmployeeA === EmployeeB // false
EmployeeA.prototype === EmployeeB.prototype // false
var emp1 = new EmployeeA("John");
var emp2 = new EmployeeB("Amit");
Object.getPrototypeOf(emp1) === EmployeeA.prototype // true
Object.getPrototypeOf(emp2) === EmployeeB.prototype // true
```

Having your `EmployeeScope` create a new class (constructor + prototype) on every new call isn't the best idea. Also you can only use it for a single instance, given that `name` is statically stored:

```
var emp3 = new EmployeeB("Dirk");
Object.getPrototypeOf(emp2) === Object.getPrototypeOf(emp3) // true
emp2.getName() // Dirk - oops
```

Your `Manager` class suffers from the same problem of course. So drop those "scope" functions and make them standard classes:

```
function Employee(newName) {
  this.name = newName;
}
Employee.prototype.getName = function() {
  return this.name
};
Employee.prototype.setName = function(newName) {
  this.name = newName
};


function Manager(newName, newDept) {
  Employee.call(this, newName);
  this.dept = newDept;
}
Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
Manager.prototype.constructor = Manager;
Manager.prototype.getDept = function() {
  return this.dept
};
Manager.prototype.setDept = function(newDept) {
  this.dept = newDept
};

var emp1 = new Employee("John");
var emp2 = new Employee("Amit");
var emp3 = new Employee("Dirk");
var mgr1 = new Manager("Robert", "Data");
var mgr2 = new Manager("Alex", "Science");
Object.getPrototypeOf(emp1) === Employee.prototype // true
Object.getPrototypeOf(emp2) === Employee.prototype // true
Object.getPrototypeOf(emp3) === Employee.prototype // true
Object.getPrototypeOf(mgr1) === Manager.prototype // true
Object.getPrototypeOf(mgr2) === Manager.prototype // true
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it makes the name and dept properties publicly accessible. Being able to keep the variables private was my main motivation behind wrapping the functions in scopes.

Comment: In that case, [create a local variable (with `var`) in the *constructor*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13418980/1048572), not some scope surrounding it. And define all methods that need to access it as closures inside the constructor scope. However, keeping `name` and `dept` "private" really isn't necessary given that there are publicly available setter and getter methods. Rather drop those and keep only the property. Simplicity rules :-)

Comment: The very same approach was suggested by Trincot's answer. It works. Thanks a lot.